# Option for comments to die after being read by intended recipient

Tags: feature-request, comments

It would often be useful if a comment disappeared when the intended recipient read it. Two cases come to mind:

- Notes of thanks, currently discouraged as polluting.
- Suggesting edits for OP to assess.

An ***option*** to have deletion done automatically would keep the site tidier and make it just a little easier to use.

Comment: And this comment shall disappear immediately after _somebody_ reads it.

Comment: I'd love to see *some* comments disappear without being flagged repeatedly, but many others shouldn't just be dismissed so easily. We'd need a way for the comment author to distinguish between the two.

Comment: If @devnull comes and posts a comment here, I won't read it, so it won't disappear. (That said, I'm not terribly against this idea.)

Comment: I don't think this is a great idea.

Just imagine the following scenarios:
- the commentator suggest changes. the OP simply deletes the comment and ignores them
- the other users might also want to see the comment
etc.

Comment: Alternatively, spring-loaded - comments disappearing in a puff of smoke after a set time.

Comment: @Andrew'saUnitato I posted a dozen comments in this thread, I assume that you've read all of those.

Comment: @devnull I tried not to read them, but there were just so many! Agghh!!